# Using Filter Function to Find Values Equal to False and Setting to True

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my Angular app I have a function that drills down to an array, and then uses a filter function to pull out values in a new array where "completed" is "false".

This is working as expected. And the way our data is, there is always one object in the array that has the property for "completed" set to "false", so I can target [0] to get to that. So, from there all I need to do is set it to "true". However, for whatever reason, how to accomplish this last step is eluding me.

This is my whole function, and what I've tried thus far:

```
private completeLastWorkflowStatus() {
    let currentService = this.checkDiscipline();
    for (let service of this.client.services) {
        if (service.service === currentService) {
            let targetWorkflow = service.workflow;
            let inCompleteWorkflow = targetWorkflow.filter(workflow => workflow.completed === false);
            console.log(inCompleteWorkflow);
            if (inCompleteWorkflow[0].completed === false) {
                inCompleteWorkflow[0].completed === true;
                console.log(inCompleteWorkflow[0].completed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the last console.log listed above, I still get "false" as the value. What am I missing here? How can I set the value of "completed" to "true" for this one object in the array?

Comment: `=` for assignment, not `===`. (Also, you don't need that `if`, because you already know that property is `false` because of the filter operation. Possibly you should test `if (inCompleteWorkflow.length > 0)` though.)

Comment: To assign a value to something, you use `=`, not `===`.

Comment: Ah, of course. So obvious now that I see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inCompleteWorkflow[0].completed === true;` is not assignment. Do `inCompleteWorkflow[0].completed = true;`